# EF5 Can I attach an Entity that was never queried from the Db?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to attach an Entity that has never been 'pulled' from the DB and have it update the existing row.  For example, I am passing a full model through in MVC (modified), and I am just trying to save it without a roundtrip to first get the entity, then edit since I already have the info from a previous call.

What I have is this:

```
public static int ModifyExistingEntity<T>(this DbContext db, T updated) where T : class
{
    DbSet<T> set = db.Set<T>();
    set.Attach(updated);
    db.Entry(updated).State = EntityState.Modified;
    return db.SaveChanges();
}
```

But when I run it I get this:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store
>   update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of
>   rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities
>   were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries. --->
>   System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or
>   delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities
>   may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh
>   ObjectStateManager entries.

Which means nothing was updated.  What am I missing here?  The primary Key is set correctly, but remember that the Entity is not pulled from the DB, it was constructed from previously queried information + updates.

Comment: never found a solution - please add one if you ever come across one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be some issue with the static extension you can try with inheritance,

```
public class MyContext:DbContext {

  public int ModifyExistingEntity<T>(this DbContext db, T updated) where T : class
  {
    DbSet<T> set = Set<T>();
    set.Attach(updated);
    this.Entry(updated).State = EntityState.Modified;
    return SaveChanges();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set.Attach(updated);
```

You don't need the above line as it is attaching the entity to the context in an unchanged state. You are probably getting the optimistic concurrency exception because the original values (db values)tracked by the context are being set to those of the updated values when attaching like this. See if using just the line below works as it both attaches the entity to the context and sets the state.

```
db.Entry(updated).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx